# Terraform EKS: get security group created by Ingress ALB

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-ingress, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I am using Terraform to create EKS cluster. The traffic is routed through AWS Application Load Balancer (ALB) - Ingress controller.

I can get the host name through following output
`kubernetes_ingress.app.status.0.load_balancer.0.ingress.0.hostname`

However, the problem is Ingress and ALB automatically create one security group, which I needed to create AWS API Gateway & VPC Link, how to get that security group's id?

Comment: Showing what your terraform config looks like would help a lot. Depending on how your terraform modules or resources are created... you could use terraform output but since you have not provided much info, it's hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

I think the link below might help you, but in case it's unavailable, you can sort of hack an LB object via the name.

You first get your LB hostname (as you already have, except split on the hyphen), then make an 'aws_lb' data type using that name, which should then populate 'aws_lb' as if you had deployed an LB. Or at least enough to be able to query that type of object to get the bits you need.

```
locals {
    lb_name_parts = split("-", split(".", kubernetes_ingress.alb_nginx_primary_ingress.status.0.load_balancer.0.ingress.0.hostname).0)
}

data "aws_lb" "alb_primary_ingress" {
    name = join("-", slice(local.lb_name_parts, 0, length(local.lb_name_parts) - 1))
}
```

(my variable for the hostname is slightly different to yours but you should get the idea)

The clever person who figured it out:

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/942